# how can i chain two none stop lists in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator, chain

I have two functions generate two none stop lists, I want to print both list, but in chain function, the second list only start to print once the first list is finished, how can I print both lists, but in turns

```
generator = chain(nonestoplist1(), nonestoplist2())
for item in generator:
  print(item)
```

like:

**first_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,......]**

**second_list=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,.....]**

generator print:

**1,a,2,b,3,c,4,d,.....**

Comment: You cn zip them nd iterate o ver the tuples zipped

Comment: This isn't quite the same as the suggested duplicate, because you want to flatten the inputs into a single iterable.  You're looking for `chain.from_iterable(zip(gen1, gen2))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item1, item2 in zip(nonestoplist1(), nonestoplist2()):
    print(item1)
    print(item2)
```